# Algorithm for moving dots (period) within an email address

Tags: c++, algorithm, gmail

For those who are not aware GMAIL allows you to create potentially unlimited number of emails based on your original email. If your email is "mygmail@gmail.com" then this can be achieved in two ways:

1) Adding text after "+" at the end of your gmail e.g. mygmail+somethinghere@gmail.com
All emails will still be sent to mygmail@gmail.com

2) Placing "." within your gmail address (except at the beginning and end) e.g. m.ygmail@gmail.com, m.y.gmail@gmail.com, m.yg.mai.l@gmail.com etc. Note: my..gmail@gmai.com and mygmail@gm.ail.com will not work!

I am testing an application that requires registering via valid email address (sends off an email activation). Method (1) is the easiest way of doing this but the email address field does not allow "+" in it. This means I need to create a database of gmail accounts using method (2).

Can someone please help with an algorithm (preferably C/C++ code) where I can provide an piece of text and it generates all the variations possible?

Some quick maths has revealed the number of possible combinations works out to be 2^(n - 1) where n is the number of characters in the email.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered that somebody could execute a DNS attack by signing up with a 101-character email address (just see how long it takes for your server to generate 2^100 strings and store them in a database).

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to accomplish? If an email address conforms to RFC3696 (section 3), it is a "valid email address", and your application should do no further checking. Are you writing special-casing code that treats the "gmail.com" domain differently from all others?

Comment: @AdamMihalcin validation could also be done with reg-ex. Not for registered emails, obviously, but valid ones.

Comment: @Jon You are absolutely correct.  But I was just explaining that implementing "an algorithm (preferably C/C++ code) where I can provide an piece of text and it generates all the variations possible" is a bad idea on a public-facing server.

Comment: Adam, I think you did not understand my post. ElKamina has provided what I was after.

Comment: @user1282312 you probably didn't understand what Adam said. Try running ElKamina's code with an e-mail with 30 or more characters and see what happens.

Comment: And that is exactly my point. I don't need to run it with any more than 15 characters.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin I think you mean DOS attack. And the OP wants to generate the emails himself for testing - not apply the algorithm to user data.

Comment: Correct Nick. Thanks to all who replied.

Comment: @NickJohnson You're right.  I'd fix the typo, but the comment is too old to edit under SO's rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def generateComb(cur,rem):
    if len(rem)>0:
        generateComb(cur +rem[0], rem[1:])
        generateComb(cur+'.'+rem[0], rem[1:])
    else:
        print cur

generateComb('m','ygmail')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for you in pseudocode. The idea is there are 2^(n - 1) combinations as you said where n is the length of the email string, so we encode the positions of the dots by a number range from 0 to 2 ^ (n - 1) - 1.

Assume s is your email address without the @ part (mygmail in your example).

```
n = length(s)
for i = 0 to 2^(n - 1) - 1
    s2 = ''
    for j = 0 to n - 2 do
        s2 = s2 + s[j]
        if (bit j in i is set)
           s2 = s2 + '.'
    s2 = s2 + s[n - 1]
    print s2
```

Now if you don't want all the 2^(n-1) combinations (may be too big if n > 15), just cap the first for loop, for example: 
for i = 0 to 999 to get first 1000 combinations.

In C/C++, 2^(n-1) translates to 1 << (n - 1), and (bit j in i is set) translate to ((i >> j) & 1).

Comment: Thanks Duc. This is even better.